# How to sync and manage data in MySQL image on docker from another server

Tags: mysql, database, docker

I have a Django application run on docker, which is based on Django RESTful API, and I can use mobile application to access data from MySQL via RESTful API. This docker run on a server on internal network.

Here is the **docker-compose.yml** of the application

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: web
    container_name: web
    restart: always
    command: gunicorn server.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 8 -k gthread
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    expose:
      - 8000
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - django_q
  metabase:
    image: metabase/metabase
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app/metabase
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    hostname: mysql
    restart: always
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --mysqlx=0
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=mysql
      - MYSQL_PORT=3307
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=kds_db
      - MYSQL_USER=****
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=****
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=****
  django_q:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: python manage.py qcluster
    container_name: django_q
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mysql
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: server-redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1337:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
```

In order to use a server to manage multiple databases on multiple servers, I'm thinking about if I could use a server have multiple databases and map them to the databases in those servers run the services.

Can anyone tell me how to automatically synchronize the data between MySQL database on the management server and MySQL database in docker on services server?